# Image Size in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I design a window like in the first picture .

[image]

I divided the frame into 3 frame and want to show image all of them . In the second picture added three image and looks good .

[image]

But when i add one image it gets out the size as you see in the third picture .

[image]

I don't want to be like that . I don't want it to gets out of the size when i add an image. How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `QWidget::setFixedSize` on your widgets holding the image in code (or alternative you can set the fixed size policy for each widget in designer) or you can use `QLayout::setSizeConstraint`.